# Search the MySQL documentation in one language and version?

Tags: mysql, documentation

Since Oracle bought MySQL the search function in the documentation doesn't work well. The top right main search field will search within the docs of all Oracle products. The bottom right search field will do the same, even though the label says "Search MySQL".

Once you've selected a particular version of the MySQL docs, e.g. [5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/), you get a search field within the left menu. This does seem to search just within the MySQL docs, but it will return results in different languages and for different versions of MySQL.

How do I search the MySQL documentation in one language and only the docs of a specific version of the software?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just a workaround: you could download the specific reference from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index.html) and search inside the downloaded document.